# "Check boxes/radio buttons" Widget is NOT displaying content in Drupal7

Tags: views

In Drupal 7 Admin, I added a choice field of Type "List (text)" and widget "Check boxes/radio buttons", in which I see the list of check boxes in the Admin.
But I don't see anything in the Live Website (it does not show up)

Below is the code that I am using in the `node-view-VIEWNAME.tpl.php` page:

```
<?php if ( render ($content['field_choice']) ): ?>
Choice(s): <?php print render ($content['field_choice']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code above works fine for Fields of Type Text. 
How would I modify the code to render the content for check-boxes?

Comment: Try after remove the if condition. Inside if condition you are rendering the element once, once it rendered then it will not render again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I had a typo in the $content[] array element.
The one I set in the admin is slightly different than the one I declared in the template.
(small typo). Amazing!

My code above also works fine with check-boxes.